# How to set up JVM variable in Maven?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a java maven project which is used as an external jar dependency for a different java maven project. The former project uses @PropertySource to fetch values from properties file and it allows to set a jvm variable called property file which can be used to set a different property file name. I want to set that variable in the latter project but no luck.

Spring Config file in the first project:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:${propertyfile:default}.properties"})
public class SpringConfig {


    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;

    }

}
```

In my second project I tried setting the propertyfile in pom.xml using the properties tag but it didn't work. I also tried using "-Dpropertyfile=custom" when I did mvn clean install and also during package but that too didn't work and it always picks the default.properties instead of custom.properties. Just to be clear default.properties would be located in the first project and custom.properties would be located in the second project. I am just wondering if it is even possible to set the jvm variable of a dependency jar ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with a dependency jar. A jar doesn't come with a JVM in it. You also don't understand the fact that JVM variables are runtime, not build time, so `mvn clean install/package/whatever` is useless.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I did the same when I did package too "mvn -Dpropertyfile=custom package -P dev cargo:run"

Comment: Update your question as "how to set JVM variables with cargo"? All the dependency jar stuff is completely irrelevant, so is the Spring config you showed.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Well just provided more context .

Comment: [how to set JVM variables with cargo](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+set+JVM+variables+with+cargo&oq=how+to+set+JVM+variables+with+cargo&aqs=chrome..69i57.3296j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Of course I did that before posting this !! Not sure if you can help me ?

Comment: I can but I won't because you came with a completely wrong problem description and a preconceived, albeit wrong, solution. You keep bringing up the dependency jar, which is just as relevant to your program as Irish Beer. You don't have cargo mentioned in your question anywhere, neither have you posted Cargo configuration, which changes based on the server you choose. Good luck.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar FYI I did change the question title. Np I am sure there would be others to help me no big deal.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar You can set environment variables when you do mvn clean install using the -D parameter. Now I realize you don't know anything and just wasting others time :( .

Comment: Well, don't expect to get paid while I do your job.